# Why index of elliptic differential operators vanishes in odd dimensional manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, elliptic-operators

Now I learn the Atiyah-Singer index theorem.
When I read an article on wikipedia of the index theorem,
I saw an fact "Index of elliptic differential operators vanish in odd dimensional manifolds".
I tried to prove it but failed.

Please tell me why index of elliptic differential operators vanish in odd dimensional manifolds and how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is proved in *Spin Geometry* by Lawson and Michelsohn, Theorem $13.12$ of chapter III.

The idea is that the diffeomorphism $c : TX \to TX$ given by $c(v) = -v$ acts on two of the three terms in (their formulation of) the formula for the topological index. One of the terms doesn't change, and the other is negated, so $\operatorname{ind}(P) = -\operatorname{ind}(P)$.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is   just a  consequence  of the  definition  and  does not  require a technical proposition or  theorem:

In  fact  the  index is  $\int_{M} ch(D)Todd(M)$ but the  differental forms in the integral  are  even  degree forms  since  they  correspond  to  characteristic  classes of  **Complex** vector  bundles. For  example we  consider the  Todd  class 
 of  the  complexification of $TM$.(In fact we  consider the  last  degree of even  graded  differential  form $ ch(D)Todd(M)$  associated to **total**  characteristic  classes of  complex bundles, which  is  obviously an  even  degree  differential form).